# Passing variables with spaces to function

Tags: bash, terminal

I have two directories in a varable and an input that is passed to the function. When I pass the two directories that have spaces in them with the incoming input from the function, I get a returned message breaking up the directory until the first space; "/Volumes/Backup/SMC", and cant be found

```
rootinput="/Volumes/Backup/SMC Media Backup/"
rootoutput="/Volumes/Backup/SMC Frameio/"

        function doPROGRAM(){
    export -f doMOVE
    selectprogram=$1
    rtout="$rootoutput$selectprogram"
    find "$rootinput$selectprogram"/Media -type f -mtime -60  -exec bash -c 'doMOVE $0 '"\"$(rtout)\"" {}   \;
    }
    doPROGRAM "Freedom House"
```

Comment: You didn't quote `RTOUT` when you finally used it.

Comment: Ive updated the code, I put double quotes around RTOUT and still the same problem

Comment: `$0` is unquoted, that's where the word splitting happens.

Answer (score 4):

Correctly written, this might look like:

```
rootInput="/Volumes/Backup/SMC Media Backup/"
rootOutput="/Volumes/Backup/SMC Frameio/"

doMove() {
  printf 'Moving %q to %q\n' "$1" "$2"
}
export -f doMove

doProgram() {
  local rtOut selectProgram
  selectProgram=$1
  rtOut="$rootOutput$selectProgram"

  find "$rootInput$selectProgram"/Media -type f -mtime -60 \
    -exec bash -c 'for arg do doMove "$arg" "$rtOut"; done' _ {} +;
}
doProgram "Freedom House"
```

Pertinent changes:

- Using previously one copy of `bash` was run per file found, here we pass as many as possible on a command line using `-exec ... {} +`, and iterate over them with `for arg do` (a synonym for `for arg in "$@"; do`).
- **Where you originally left `$0` unquoted, here we quote `"$arg"`; this lack of quoting was the immediate cause of the undesired wordsplitting.**

Stylistic / best-practice changes:

- Per POSIX guidelines documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, we use lower-case names for our own variables, staying out of the reserved all-caps namespace used for names meaningful to the shell itself and other POSIX-specified tools.
- We're avoiding mixing POSIX and ksh function-declaration syntax, as described in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (`function foo {`  is ksh-compatible; `foo() {` is POSIX-compliant; `function foo() {` is neither POSIX-compliant nor compatible with legacy ksh)
- We're explicitly declaring variables assigned in functions for use in those functions `local`; that way they don't unexpectedly change variables in global scope when called.

Comment: `%q` quotes content to be printable/human-readable (and to `eval` back to itself), even if it has hidden characters. So, for example, it prints a name with a DOS newline as `$'name\r'`, so you can actually see the `\r` -- the carriage return -- at the end.